# TokenMismatchException during AJAX polling in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, csrf, csrf-protection

In my Laravel application, I have a notification system. This is run using AJAX polling techniques (i.e. a ajax post function is run every 5 seconds or so) similar to:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': CSRF_TOKEN
    }
});

(function pollForNewNotifications() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://example.com/get-notifications',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    // data that is sent
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    // add new notifications if data is not empty logic
                    pollForNewNotifications();
                }
            })
            .fail(function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(xhr.responseText)
            });
    }, 5000);
})();
```

Now this works most of the time.

However, the issue is that I sometimes find that over long period of inactivity I get a `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php` error and automatically logged out.

I believe that this is the case because the CSRF token changes or longer is valid (I may be wrong).

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Change the session's lifetime:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/a282304/config/session.php#L32

Comment: Although that may help, if I set it to a number (let's say 5000), then the issue would just arise again in 5000 minutes. I wanted it so that the session understands that it's not actually idle, but doing something.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove token check to this particular url so it can make request without checking csrf token. Go to `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`

place this

```
protected $except = [
   'get-notifications',
];
```